# How to aggregate a pytorch tensor to a smaller size?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm new to pytorch and tensors and I'm wondering how to do the following. I'll explain with a super simple example:

If I have a 1d tensor of 9 values - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
I'd like to "aggregate" or reduce this tensor by some ratio - let's say 3 for the example. In this case, I would like to aggregate (mean, sum, whatever function) of the first 3 into one value, second 3 into another value, etc...

Let's say I'd like to use sum as the aggregating function. So [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] would turn into a new tensor that would look like [6, 15, 24]

Is there a built in pytorch way of doing this or some other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the answer in the docs so I'll put it here.

This function and related ones: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.avg_pool1d.html#torch.nn.functional.avg_pool1d

code:

```html
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F
input = torch.tensor([[[2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9]]], dtype=torch.float32)
F.avg_pool1d(input, kernel_size=3, stride=3)
```

output:
tensor([[[2.3333, 5.3333, 8.3333]]])